# Beautiful Soup 4 .string() 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[2]), 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify)

if sys.argv[1] == "h":
    h2s = soup.find_all("h2")
    for h in h2s:
        print(h.string())
```

The first print statement (added as a test) works - so I know BS4 is working and everything.
The second print statement throws:

```
File "sp2gd.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(h.string())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeautifulSoup's [`.string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) is a property, not a callable method, and when there's no single, unambiguous string representation of the contents of the element (for instance, when it contains multiple child elements), its value is `None` – hence the error message.

Lose the parentheses `()` after `h.string` and you'll stop getting errors:

```
if sys.argv[1] == "h":
    h2s = soup.find_all("h2")
    for h in h2s:
        print(h.string)  # no parentheses
```

... although if the `h2` elements have multiple children, the results might not be especially illuminating. In that case, [`.strings` and `.stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) come in handy:

```
if sys.argv[1] == "h":
    h2s = soup.find_all("h2")
    for h in h2s:
        for s in h.stripped_strings:
            print(s)
```