# Update text in a <p> tag in HTML that contains <img> tag using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following Beautifulsoup HTML tag that I want to update the text `TEXT TO BE UPDATED` in the tag to `SOMETHING ELSE`.

```html
<p><img src="./img.jpg"> TEXT TO BE UPDATED.</p>
```

Let's say that the Beautifulsoup object of the above `<p>` tag is `p_tag`. I tried to use `p_tag.string.replace_with('SOMETHING ELSE')`, but it does not work because `p_tag.string` always returns `None`. Any idea why it happened?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `p_tag.text` to get the text, and `p_tag.string` to set the new text.

Like so:

```py
source = '<p><img src="./img.jpg"> TEXT TO BE UPDATED.</p>'
bsoup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
p_tag = bsoup.p

old_text = p_tag.text
new_text = p_tag.img.text + ' Something new'
p_tag.string = new_text
print(p_tag.prettify())
#  prints `<p><img src="./img.jpg"> Something new </p>`
```

Comment: I have tried your code and in the result, the `<img>` element in `<p>` has been stripped-off too. This does not work as I expected.

Comment: According to your question you wanted to replace the `<p>` tag content, which includes `<img>` as well. Edited the answer to retain the `<img>` tag.

Comment: What you tried was correct, i.e `p_tag.string.replace_with('new')`, but it wouldn't in this case as string property will be None (for reason why look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40615308). )